# DropDownButton with Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

For display categoryList in dropdownbutton I am using Cubit, its working. My problem: is it possible to use Cubit for showing selectedCategory? Without to use setState? Now when select category it doesnt show me selectedCategory.
Cubit:

```
class CategoriesCubit extends Cubit<CategoriesState> {
  final DataBase dataBase;
  final Category category;

  CategoriesCubit(this.dataBase, this.category)
      : super(CategoriesInitial());
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  Future getCategories() async {
    streamSubscription = dataBase.getCategories().listen((data) {
      emit(CategoriesLoaded(data));
    });
  }
  void setCategory(String selectedCategory) {
    category.categoryID = selectedCategory;
  }
}
```

Main:

```
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CategoriesCubit(DataBase(), Category()),
      child: DropDownButton(),
    );
  }
}

class DropDownButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.bloc<CategoriesCubit>().getCategories();
    final category = context.bloc<CategoriesCubit>().category;
    return Container(
      child: BlocBuilder<CategoriesCubit, CategoriesState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is CategoriesLoaded) {
            return DropdownButton(
              value: category.categoryID,
              hint: Text('choose category'),
              items: state.categories
                  .map((category) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(category.categoryName),
                        value: category.categoryID,
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (selectedCategory) {
                context.bloc<CategoriesCubit>().setCategory(selectedCategory);
                print(selectedCategory);
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation of a `Cubit` has some issues.

1. `Cubit`s should be immutable. You shouldn't keep state in a variable inside of them which you're doing right now with `category` variable.
2. You're retrieving current selected category outside of `BlocBuilder` and It's not gonna update when `Cubit`'s state is changed.
3. When you're calling `setCategory`, `Cubit`'s state is kept unchanged since you're not emitting anything.
4. Your `CategoriesCubit` has mission of controlling category's fetching state. It's better if you don't add another task to it.

I suggest keeping the `selectedCategoryId` as an internal state in your widget unless you need to share it among multiple widgets or preserve it in It's ancestors.